# Pyspark: Performance of using toPandas()

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I have an iterative optimization procedure which includes some pyspark queries (which have parameters) on a relatively big dataframe (700000 rows). My question concerns the use of toPandas () and whether my structure could be improved. The procedure goes like this:

Given: Set of initial parameters for the queries

Initial step: load data and transform to pyspark dataframe (df_spark = spark.createDataFrame(data))

run for x iterations:

```
Step 1. execute some queries on df_spark (using current set of parameters)
        --> result is a new dataframe ("new_frame_spark")

Step 2. transform "new_frame_spark" to pandas using toPandas()

Step 3. perform a few calculations on new_frame
        --> result is a single number ("result_number")

Step 4. Based on "result_number", change current set of parameters and start over with Step 1.
```

On the whole, the procedure works well, but Step 2 is a big problem because this conversion takes a lot of time. I have also tried to do step 3 on "new_frame_spark" as well and then to convert the resulting number "result_number" to numpy using collect(). Unfortunately, that also took a long time.

Is there any way to speed up the procedure?

Thank you very much!

Comment: why not  'perform a few calculations' on the spark df? Without more details it's hard to say anything

Comment: I have already tried that. But afterwards I need this single number "result_number" which I have to convert by using collect(). And I had the feeling that using collect () takes just as long at this point.

Comment: you had a feeling? Did you try it? Again, we are going to need details, some form of a [mcve]

Comment: As I said: Yes, I tried it. I will try to create a minimal example. Although my question is more of a general nature.

Comment: You can speed up conversion `toPandas` with Apache Arrow: see [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-pyspark-pandas-with-arrow.html). You will need `PyArrow` installed.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that. I am a Pyspark beginner and have only little experience so far. But what I noticed is the following: If I convert the entire dataframe with toPandas (), it takes (strangely) exactly as long as if I only convert one column of the dataframe using toPandas ().

Comment: I have tried the commands:

spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled", "true")
spark.conf.set('spark.sql.execution.arrow.maxRecordsPerBatch', x)

and used different value for x. 

df_spark = spark.createDataFrame(data)
print('Start test')
start = time.time()
test = df_spark.toPandas()
end = time.time()
print(end - start)
print('End pandas test')

Using arrow had no effect in my example.

Comment: Spark actions (e.g. toPandas, collect) should avoided in your iterations if at all possible. Can you keep everything in dataframes and only collect as a final action after you have finished iterating? To do this, you will need to calculate the parameters at the end of one iteration and use them in the next with dataframe transformation only e.g. join.